# PDFBox error - java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: pdfbox

We are using PDFBox 1.8.9 to create PDF documents. We are getting below exception from our testing server.

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceGray.()V from class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream
       at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream.(PDPageContentStream.java:74)
       at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream.(PDPageContentStream.java:173)
       at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream.(PDPageContentStream.java:158)
       at com.fedex.cal.clmc.transaction.clms.claims.LetterToPDFTransaction.convertToPDF(LetterToPDFTransaction.java:96)

The exception triggered at line #96 in our source code where below is the line of code there.
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document,page);

In our local environment we are not facing this issue and it is working fine. We are using maven and below is the pom dependency.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>fedex.cxs.commonlib</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fedex.cxs.commonlib</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: `We are using PDFBox 1.8.9` no you are using PDFBox 1.7.1 and FontBox 1.8.9. Consider using PDFBox 1.8.12 or 2.0.3, these are the current versions. And the group id `fedex.cxs.commonlib` is not the official one.

Comment: Tilman - Thanks for your reply. I updated version 1.8.9 which is the correct one. We have org specific maven repository. That is the reason you are seeing different groupId

Comment: What happens if you have only `new PDDeviceGray()` in your code? Same problem? Maybe compare your pdfbox jar file with the official one, and make sure that you don't have different versions in your classpath.